# Creating named range fails in French Excel

Tags: excel, vba, localization

Update:

Saving the RefersTo off into a variable and re-setting the RefersTo after setting the Comment appears to workaround the issue.

```
Public Sub TestOneFixed()

    Dim n As Name
    Dim s As String

    Set n = ActiveSheet.Names.Add("TestOne", ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E8"))
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    Debug.Print n.RefersToRange.Address

    Set n = ActiveSheet.Names.Add("TestTwo", ActiveSheet.Range("A10:E18"))
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    s = n.RefersTo
    n.Comment = "zoltan"
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    n.RefersTo = s
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    Debug.Print n.RefersToRange.Address

End Sub
```

Updated:
In French Excel version 1902 (build 11328.20438) this code is failing:

```
Public Sub TestOne()

    Dim n As Name

    Set n = ActiveSheet.Names.Add("TestOne", ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E8"))
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    Debug.Print n.RefersToRange.Address

    Set n = ActiveSheet.Names.Add("TestTwo", ActiveSheet.Range("A10:E18"))
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    n.Comment = "zoltan"
    Debug.Print n.RefersTo
    Debug.Print n.RefersToRange.Address    '<--- error 1004 thrown here

End Sub
```

The immediate window shows:

```
=Feuil1!$A$1:$E$8
$A$1:$E$8
=Feuil1!$A$10:$E$18
=Feuil1!L10C1:L18C5
```

In my English Excel version 1910 (build 12130.20344) the same code produces

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:$E$8
$A$1:$E$8
=Sheet1!$A$10:$E$18
=Sheet1!$A$10:$E$18
$A$10:$E$18
```

(previous iteration of question; didn't have full user feedback on test case) -----------

In the code below, I'm creating a named range an passing in a range as the RefersTo parameter. Works fine in English Excel (I happen to be using Excel 365 64-bit). For some reason, even though r.Address in the Immediate window shows B3:E8, the named range that is created shows 'SheetName'!'L3C3':'L5C8' (not the exact values) which is the French version of R1C1. But n.RefersToRange throws an error because it no longer recognizes the RefersTo as a range.

Is this issue familiar to anyone and is there a good workaround? Best I can tell so far, this issue has only popped up in one place in the application code and I've never seen anything like this before on the English side.

```
    Dim n As Name
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E8")
    Set n = ActiveSheet.Names.Add("TestOne", r)
    debug.print n.RefersToRange.Columns.Count   '<--- error is here because RefersToRange does not return a Range reference
```

[image: visual of the issue]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error is 1004. The issue is that RefersToRange doesn't return a range. I hit save accidentally early and have finished the full post.

Comment: I can't test this, but my guess is that you need to use other parameters of [`Names.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.names.add), maybe `RefersToR1C1Local` but not sure, a bit of a shot in the dark.

Comment: Would `ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="TestOne", RefersTo:=r` do the exact same thing? Just to rule some sort of glitch out

Comment: No repro. Did `set n = sheet1.Names.Add("test", sheet1.Range("B3:E8"))` in the immediate pane, then `?n.referstorange.address` and the output was `$B$3:$E$8`. @JvdV yes it would, they're the first two parameters.

Comment: I sent a workbook to the user to test that very guess, JvdV. Have not heard back yet. Also attaching an image to the OP. You can see the name is created, just not "usuable" as a range.

Comment: I understand that @MathieuGuindon, just wondering if it would be some sort of glitch using other syntax....

Comment: Another shot in the dark, to rule out your client uses R1C1 notation which messes up something somehow (who knows) maybe you can set the referencestyle to xlA1 in your code. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.referencestyle)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon doesn't [Name.Refersto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.refersto) return a string not a range?

Comment: @ScottCraner perhaps, but here it is the [Names.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.add) method's `RefersTo` argument

Comment: I'm fairly certain the R1C1 reference checkbox was off. In the application, the value is coming from a RefEdit control and was showing A1 notation as expected. The worksheet was also showing A, B, C across the top.

Comment: Name.RefersTo will return a string. Name.RefersToRange will return a range if the text can be converted. That is why you can see =#REF!A1:B10 in the dialog and get "=#REF!A1:B10" from RefersTo but RefersToRange will error.

Comment: Is this your real actual code, or just *something that looks like it*? Working off whatever sheet is currently active is rather suspicious.

Comment: This is a simplification. I'm trying to reconnect with them to get a better set of debug messages. Its been working fine for years in English Excel, but this is our first experience with French Excel (not just a French keyboard layout).

Comment: I'd warmly recommend putting up the *actual relevant code* rather than a simplification of it -- some critical parts were likely left out.

Comment: I have tried the code on a German Excel and it worked. Can you try on a completely new workbook? It should work.

Comment: I dropped the full code in question in the post. DataSetAddress is a string. rng is correct. n is a Name and is created. Then when we loop over the columns of the range it dies. I tried variations of the Range(DataSetAddress) in various places (such as the simplication I posted) and had the same results.

Comment: @Vityata the code is in an addin (XLAM) and running against new workbooks that they create.

Comment: Ok. After running with some of the ideas here and getting back onto a screen share with them, I've isolated the issue to the RefersTo changing when a Comment is added to the name. I don't know the proper StackOverflow-fu.... Should I close this and open a new item or edit the OP?

Comment: Way off idea: Try using `Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(18, 5)))` instead of a string for the Range reference.